# Most efficient way to format a hash of data?

Tags: ruby, hash, formatting

I am using this array of hashes to do a batch insert into a mongo DB. Each hash was populated by parsing a text file so the formatting of fields are in an unpredictable format.  It might look something like:

```
{date => "March 5", time => "05:22:21", first_name = "John", middle_initial = "JJ", ...}
```

And I would have a series of formatting functions.  So maybe:

```
def format_date
..convert if needed..
end

def format_time
...
end
```

How would I go about calling the formatting functions on various records?  I could see doing some kind of lambda call where I iterate through the hash and call a format_record_name function, but not all records will have formatting functions.  For instance above the first_name record wouldn't need one. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't totally get the question. Given this input, what is the expected output?

Comment: Sorry I updated the question.  Hopefully it's clearer..

Comment: You should put examples of when you want to change what kind of data into what form. The question is not stated enough.

Comment: Should I edit this or just keep it in mind the next time I have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea, pretty similar to what you stated.  You might just have an identity function for the fields you don't want to format

```
def pass(x)
   x
end 

method_hash = {:date=>method(:your_format_date)}
method_hash.default = method(:pass)

x = {:date => "March 5", :time => "05:22:21", :first_name => "John", :middle_initial => "JJ"}
x.reduce({}) { |hsh,k|  hsh[k[0]] = method_hash[k[0]].call(k[1]); hsh }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just keep a list of the keys that you do want to handle. You could even tie it to the transformation functions with a Hash:

```
transformations = { 
  :date => lambda {|date| whatever},
  :time => lambda {|time| whatever} 
}
transformations.default = lambda {|v| v}

data.map do |hash|
  Hash[ hash.map {|key, val| transformations[key][val] } ]
end
```

Comment: This looks like an elegant solution, but I don't understand what to put inside of :date => lambda {|date| whatever}.  I've tried all kinds of ways of accessing the value in :date and can't seem to.  But I also can't seem to just return a fake value either.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Ruby's Singleton (or Eigen) class and then the following one liner solves your problem:

```
module Formatter
  def format_date
    Date.parse(self[:date]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  end

  def format_time
    self[:time].split(':')[0,2].join('-')
  end

  def format_first_name
    self[:first_name].upcase
  end

  def format
    {:date => format_date, :time => format_time, :first_name => format_first_name, :last_name => self[:last_name]}
  end
end

records = [
  {:date => 'March 05', :time => '12:13:00', :first_name => 'Wes', :last_name => 'Bailey'},
  {:date => 'March 06', :time => '09:15:11', :first_name => 'Joe', :last_name => 'Buck'},
  {:date => 'March 07', :time => '18:35:48', :first_name => 'Troy', :last_name => 'Aikmen'},
]

records.map {|h| h.extend(Formatter).format}
=> [{:date=>"2011-03-05", :time=>"12-13", :first_name=>"WES", :last_name=>"Bailey"},
 {:date=>"2011-03-06", :time=>"09-15", :first_name=>"JOE", :last_name=>"Buck"},
 {:date=>"2011-03-07", :time=>"18-35", :first_name=>"TROY", :last_name=>"Aikmen"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Formatters
    def self.time(value)
        "FORMATTED TIME"
    end

    def self.date(value)
        "FORMATTED DATE"
    end

    def self.method_missing(name, arg)
        arg
    end
end

your_data = [{:date => "March 5", :time => "05:22:21", :first_name => "John", :middle_initial => "JJ"},
             {:date => "March 6", :time => "05:22:22", :first_name => "Peter", :middle_initial => "JJ"},
             {:date => "March 7", :time => "05:22:23", :first_name => "Paul", :middle_initial => "JJ"}]

formatted_data = your_data.map do |item|    
    Hash[ *item.map { |k, v| [k, Formatters.send(k, v)] }.flatten ]
end
```